# Grub warning- xen

Tags: grub2, xen

When I run `update-grub` I get the following warning on my Ubuntu KVM hypervisor:

```
Including Xen overrides from /etc/default/grub.d/xen.cfg
WARNING: GRUB_DEFAULT changed to boot into Xen by default!
         Edit /etc/default/grub.d/xen.cfg to avoid this warning.
```

I find this really strange as I am running KVM and have never intentionally installed xen.

If I perform `sudo apt-get remove xen-hypervisor-amd64` I get the output

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'xen-hypervisor-4.4-amd64' instead of 'xen-hypervisor-amd64'
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
```

Is there something I should do to ensure that my machine does not have a xen kernel and isn't going to try and boot into one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit late, I know, but I just had a similar issue and solved it by renaming `/etc/default/grub.d/xen.cfg` to `/etc/default/grub.d/xen.cfg_bak`, so grub does not find it and then just removes it from the menu .

Apparently Xen does not remove the grub configurations upon uninstallation, so just hiding them and then updating my grub (via `update-grub` on Ubuntu 15.10) was enough to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me:

apt purge xen*

The "purge" option removes the package and the configuration files.

"xen*" (with the glob at the end) has apt trying to uninstall every package that starts with xen, whether or not it's installed on your system. A surgical removal one package at a time is the better option if you have the time and sufficient brain cells.